# Neovim clangd semantic highlighting

Tags: lsp, neovim-qt

So I'm using [nvim-lsp-clangd-highlight](https://github.com/adam-wolski/nvim-lsp-clangd-highlight) plugin to try and set up semantic highlighting with clangd

in my ~/.config/nvim/init.nvim

```
call plug#begin()
    Plug 'neovim/nvim-lsp'
    Plug 'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'
    Plug 'williamboman/mason.nvim'
    Plug 'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim'
    Plug 'adam-wolski/nvim-lsp-clangd-highlight'
    ...
call plug#end()
```

I've done `:PlugInstall` and `:PlugUpdate`

in my ~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins.lua...

```
local nvim_lsp_clangd_highlight = require'nvim-lsp-clangd-highlight'

require('lspconfig')['clangd'].setup({
   on_attach = on_attach,
   cmd = {
      clangd_path,
      "--header-insertion=never"
   },
   capabilities = {
      textDocument = {
         semanticHighlightingCapabilities = {
            semanticHighlighting = true
         }
      }
   },
   on_init = nvim_lsp_clangd_highlight.on_init
})
```

in my ~/.config/nvim/ginit.vim...

```
augroup ConfigSetup
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter,ColorScheme * runtime syntax/custom_colors.vim
augroup END
```

I've used [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adam-wolski/nvim-lsp-clangd-highlight/master/syntax/nvim-lsp-clangd-highlight.vim) default script for my ~/.config/nvim/syntax/custom_colors.vim

I know that clangd is working, my hover key command works and errors are pointed out. But I can't get clangd's full semantic highlighting to work.

If I use the command `hi Type guifg=Black` only the built in types change color, anything user defined stays the same. If I use the command `hi Namespace guifg=Black` nothing changes and I have places with `std::...` or custom namespaces where I believe it should.

Does anyone know what I'm missing? What should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working using [this plugin](https://github.com/jackguo380/vim-lsp-cxx-highlight) and the following in my coc-settings.json

```
{
    "clangd.enabled": true,
    "[cpp]": {
        "inlayHint.enable": false,
        "semanticTokens.enable": true
    }
}
```

Comment: May be could you accept your own answer using the v button next to the arrow coming buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)